# I ran bluestacks on Android Studio but Logcat window of Android Studio does not show anything

Tags: android, bluestacks

I ran `bluestacks` on `Android Studio` but `Logcat` window of `Android Studio` does not show anything, how can I see the logs?

Comment: May be `Invalid cache and restart` will help.you can find that option in `file` menu at the top bar.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the app is launched on `blustacks`, it does not automatically change the Logcat setting too
Logcat has a menu to select the emulator or real device